# I need to send product details to Google shopping Content API but first i need to generate oAuth token.How i will do it through function app

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, google-shopping-api

I need to send product details to Google shopping Content API  but for using that i need to generate oAuth token with refresh token throgh Azure data factory.I have generated service account and client-secret json .How i will do it through function app?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to understand that functions should not be used to do UI-related actions. In any app service the pop up for the login ( which allows to provide the credentials) will not be supported.

E.g. : To avoid this scenario , in case of AD auth we may use service principle where we feed the required credential to acquire the token. So if we want to use the google auth SDK we need to connect to the concerned team ( Google team) to understand if this is feasible at all.

For this you may check the Server-To-Server Service Account Authentication, as below:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

In case you need any assistance in this, we would recommend you to reach out to the concerned support team.